# Remove several strings between two specific characters

Tags: r, regex

I need help with regex in R.
I have a bunch of strings each of which has a structure similar to this one:

```
mytext <- "\"Dimitri. It has absolutely no meaning,\": Allow me to him|\"realize that\": Poor Alice! It |\"HIGHLIGHT A LOT OF THINGS. Our team is small and if each person highlights only 1 or 2 things, the counts of Likes\": |\"same for the Dislikes.  Thank you very much for completing this\": ME.' 'You!' sai"
```

Notice that this strings contains substrings within "" followed by a ":" and some text without quotation marks - until we encounter a "|" - then a new quotation mark appears etc.

Notice also that at the very end there is text after a ":" - but at the VERY end there is no "|"

My objective is to completely eliminate all text starting with any ":" (and INCLUDING ":") and until the next "|" (but "|" has to stay). I also need to eliminate all text that comes after the very last ":"

Finally (that's more of a bonus) - I want to get rid of all "\" characters and all quotation marks - because in the final solution I need to have "clean text": A bunch of strings separated only by "|" characters.

Is it possible?

Here is my awkward first attempt:

```
gsub('\\:.*?\\|', '', mytext)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a single `gsub` you can match text after a `:` (including the `:`), so long as it doesn't contain a pipe: `:[^|]*`.  This matches the case at the end of the string, too. You can also match double quotes by searching for another pattern after the alternation character (`|`):  `[\"]`

```
gsub(":[^|]*|[\"]", "", mytext)
#[1] "Dimitri. It has absolutely no meaning,|realize that|HIGHLIGHT A LOT OF THINGS. Our team is small and if each person highlights only 1 or 2 things, the counts of Likes|same for the Dislikes.  Thank you very much for completing this"
```

Comment: Wow, guys, thank you very much, Especially the last solution is so elegant!

Comment: From the User Experience perspective - it'd help people do the right thing (click on "check") if it were somehow made more obvious, e.g.: Click on check if you accept this answer:

Comment: @user3245256 There could probably be some sort of improvements in that realm.  But, now that you know, you can go back and accept answers to your previous questions, if they have been answered properly.

Answer (score 2):

This method uses 3 passes of `g?sub`.

```
sub("\\|$", "", gsub("[\\\\\"]", "", gsub(":.*?(\\||$)", "|", mytext)))
[1] "Dimitri. It has absolutely no meaning,|realize that|HIGHLIGHT A LOT OF THINGS. Our team is small and if each person highlights only 1 or 2 things, the counts of Likes|same for the Dislikes.  Thank you very much for completing this"
```

The first strips out the text in between ":" and "|" inclusive and replaces it with "|". The second pass removes "\" and """ and the third pass removes the "|" at the end.